# What is the quickest way to kill the Ninth Sister?

Tags: star-wars-jedi-fallen-order

Yes, it is easy to kill the ninth sister with time and patience, but I need a fast and reliable way to do this if I want to speedrun the Kashyyyk level. Preferably something that uses the single lightsaber but if that is not possible I can use the double-bladed lightsaber.